# jquery - Check if there is text in a textfield

Tags: jquery, search, input, find

I have some textfields where I would like to check if they have text within them.

```
<input type="text" class="inputField" id="a113" name="grp113">cm</div>
```

Can you help me find the error in the following code? :)

```
if ($(this).find('input[type="text"]').length > 0) 
{
    alert("there is text in the field");
}
else
{
    alert("there is no text in the field");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're checking whether there any text boxes in your DOM. I suspect you want something like the following:

```
$(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        alert("there is text in the field");
    } else {
        alert("there is no text in the field");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a jQuery object, you need to get the value of the text field - you can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the value of an input field

```
if ($(this).find('input[type="text"]').val().length > 0) {
    alert("there is text in the field");
} else {
    alert("there is no text in the field");
}
```

Comment: It does't do anything now. It stops all my other code from running. What do you think it could be?